# How to know the response of a callback rest call protractor

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I am running an automation script. We have a scenario where Java makes a callback REST call to UI. Below is the code where am doing httpGet to that URL. I want to know when the response comes. If it comes how to know that. I searched a lot I din't find a clear answer anywhere. Please give some hints!

```
http.get(siteUrl, function(response) {

        var bodyString = '';

        response.setEncoding('utf8');

        response.on("data", function(chunk) {
            bodyString += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            defer.fulfill({
                statusCode: response.statusCode,
                bodyString: bodyString
            });
        });

    }).on('error', function(e) {
        defer.reject("Got http.get error: " + e.message);
    });

//If we are sure that response has come, then extract it
    httpGet("http://testurl").then(function(result) {
        //alert('inside test automation');
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-http-client to make API calls from protractor tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the response detail whether success or fail with "response code", there are lots of way using interface as callback, using methods by checking response code, lots of network library available - volley, okhttp  [rest client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) etc...

help :  [response code detail](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_status_codes.htm)

```
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    // do success work read response etc...
    // you can call methods what you want if success happen 
} else { 
    // you can check other status code too..
    // call methods if api get fail.
}
```

Hope this would help

good luck.